# Client Socket not receiving/reading response correctly

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, bufferedreader, outputstream

I have a server, and I connect to it perfectly and receives messages if I work with node.js and javascript.

I started an app on Android Studio that has an `EditText` and `TextView` attributes.

My goal is to type in the `EditText` press send and send that msg to the server and print the response in the `TextView`.

For some reason I can't get it to work, and I can see the `Socket` does connect when I debug it. But I can't seem to get the responses from the server as I would in my js example.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    String response = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintStream out = null;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 80;
    private static final String ONLY_HOST = "myServer.azurewebsites.net";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messages);

        ClientThread client = new ClientThread();
        client.execute();


    }

    class ClientThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                socket = new Socket(ONLY_HOST, SERVERPORT);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                    response += new String(buffer);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                Log.e("UnknownHost","Socket not starting" );
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e("IO Exception","Socket not starting" );
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (tv != null) {
                tv.setText(response);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }


    public void sendIt(View v)  {
        try {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.write(et.getText().toString().getBytes());
                out.flush();

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            Log.e("sendIt","1st" );
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.e("sendIt","2nd" );
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will do i've been on this too long already.

Thanks!

Comment: And why did you delete the former post about exactly this? You should have reacted on my comments instead and provided the asked information. Do you think its funny to see comments and remarks diappeared? Undelete it and we will continue.

Comment: Because I made a typo, and all the answers were regarding the fact my socket is not connecting(and it is), and after I fixed it I got no answers regarding my problem. So I posted a fixed post.

Comment: Try this: dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                            socket.getInputStream()); messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF(); textviev.setText(messageFromClient)

Comment: `and after I fixed it I got no answers regarding my problem.`. You did. And questions. And you did not react. And my last comment i could not post anymore. Is this the way to `Thanks!` people who give you your time?

Comment: I refreshed a few time and saw nothing. Why would I delete it if I had answers I could use? You think i'm lying? come on leave me alone

Comment: I saw your answer there "You are trying to read the response directly after the connection. And you do not try to read a response after you send some text." what do u recommend i should use? different thread?